# Space does not disappear if table output is turned off

Tags: r, shiny

I want to show to user as much lines as he wants. If he does not want it, I show nothing.

However if I show something and then nothing, table disappears but space for it remains. Is there a way to remove space also?

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Reproducible example

```
require(shiny)
if (interactive()) {
    ui <- fluidPage(
        column(4,
               selectInput("select", label = h3("How many rows"), 
                           choices = list("0" = 0, "3" = 3, "6" = 6, "9" = 9), 
                           selected = 3)
        ),
        column(8,
               verbatimTextOutput("Warning_1"),
               dataTableOutput("table"),
               verbatimTextOutput("Warning_2"))

    )
    server <- function(input, output) {

        output$Warning_1 <- renderText({
            answer <- paste("We show", input$select, "rows")
        })

        output$Warning_2 <- renderText({
            answer <- paste("As I said we show", input$select, "rows")
        })

        output$table <- renderDataTable({

            if (input$select == "0") {
                return()
            } else {

                dt <- head(mtcars, as.numeric(input$select))
                return(dt)
            }

        },
        options = list(
            lengthMenu = list(c(5, 15, -1), c('5', '15', 'All')),
            pageLength = 15)
        )
    }


    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```

UPDATE TO CLARIFY QUESTION:

This space marked with red cross should disappear if I choose 0 lines to show.

[image: This space marked with red cross should disappear if I choose 0 lines to show.]

Also session info just in case:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.3

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] DT_0.2           data.table_1.9.6 jsonlite_1.1     plotly_4.5.2    
[5] ggplot2_2.1.0    shiny_1.0.0     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.7       magrittr_1.5      munsell_0.4.3     viridisLite_0.1.3
 [5] colorspace_1.2-7  xtable_1.8-2      R6_2.2.0          httr_1.2.1       
 [9] plyr_1.8.4        dplyr_0.5.0       tools_3.3.2       grid_3.3.2       
[13] gtable_0.2.0      DBI_0.5-1         htmltools_0.3.5   yaml_2.1.13      
[17] lazyeval_0.2.0    digest_0.6.10     assertthat_0.1    tibble_1.2       
[21] tidyr_0.6.1       purrr_0.2.2       base64enc_0.1-3   htmlwidgets_0.7  
[25] mime_0.5          labeling_0.3      RevoUtils_10.0.2  scales_0.4.0     
[29] chron_2.3-47      httpuv_1.3.3     
>
```

Comment: I don't see what you mean. If I specify zero, it does not show the datatable at all, which seems to be what you want. I don't see any empty space where the datatable was. Can you describe your problem more precisely?

Comment: @MikeWise Mike I appreciate your care indeed. I add pic and session info to clarify my question. I do hope you can help me.

Comment: I see. That is not what I see on my Windows 10 PC. The area you marked with a red-X does not exist, those two row status messages are right on top of each other. My session info is much the same as your except I am using R version 3.3.3. Works fine in the browser too, using Chrome.

Comment: Does your work in the browser?

Comment: @MikeWise Mike, I am on Mac/Safari. Thank you for information, I will find PC and try on it.

Comment: Try it in the browser first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by `renderUI`, the `eval(parse(...))` of the shiny world. It is a bit heavy-handed, but if you're insistent on the functionality this is an option.

```
library("shiny")
ui <- fluidPage(
  column(4,
         selectInput("select", label = h3("How many rows"),
                     choices = list("0" = 0, "3" = 3, "6" = 6, "9" = 9),
                     selected = 3)
  ),
  uiOutput("disappearing_table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$Warning_1 <- renderText({
    answer <- paste("We show", input$select, "rows")
  })

  output$Warning_2 <- renderText({
    answer <- paste("As I said we show", input$select, "rows")
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    head(mtcars, as.numeric(input$select))
  },

  options = list(
    lengthMenu = list(c(5, 15, -1), c('5', '15', 'All')),
    pageLength = 15)
  )

  output$disappearing_table <- renderUI({
    if (input$select == "0") {
      column(8,
             verbatimTextOutput("Warning_1"),
             verbatimTextOutput("Warning_2")
      )
    } else {
      column(8,
             verbatimTextOutput("Warning_1"),
             dataTableOutput("table"),
             verbatimTextOutput("Warning_2")
      )
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Collapsed when no rows selected:

[image]

Expands to needed space when called:

[image]

Comment: mlegge thank you very much indeed for your solution. I somehow missed your post but now I have found it. Everything works perfectly now!